# Node Wrangler: Lazy connect uses alpha instead of color

Tags: node-editor

According to the keymap, the Node Wrangler addon uses ALT + RMB for lazy connect. But when i use this shortcut to connect diffuse textures to the Principled Shader, it unexpectedly connects the alpha socket instead of color, which doesn't make much sense. How do i change it so that the color sockets are used?

Comment: I agrre that this behaviour is a bit counter-intuitive or counter-productive. You have an alternative "less lazy" connect with "shift" + "alt" + RMB. Or you can double lazy connect and then cut the alpha link with "CTRL" + RMB drag since the second connect will connect the color to the color. Other than that I think you would have to modify the code inside the add-on to change the behaviour.

Comment: So this problem is still it is. 3 years